# Angular Filter based on Multiselect-Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, multi-select, angular-filters

I use nya-bootstrap-select directive (http://nya.io/nya-bootstrap-select/)
for  a Multiselect-Dropdown ( Angular 1.5.8 ). 
Now I would like to filter a collection based on the selected options.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mrtzdev/2z6xfo5w/18/

```
<ol id="dynamic-options" class="nya-bs-select" ng-model="model2" multiple >
  <li nya-bs-option="(key,value) in companyList" >
    <a>{{ value.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Filtered Collection:

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="client in clients | filter:{ name: model1.name, company: { name: model2.name } } ">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td><em>{{client.name}}</em>

            </td>
            <td>{{client.designation}}</td>
            <td>{{client.company.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

This obviously does not work for the multiselect.  How can use a custom filter, to filter on multi-selected options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udbgs6od/6/) and make it work. This filter is not good in dynamic handling but it will allow you to filter your data by the exact filter attribute `name`.

#### View

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients | filter:{ name: model1.name} | inArrayExact : { myArray: model2, searchKey: 'name', filterKey: 'company' }">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td><em>{{client.name}}</em>

    </td>
    <td>{{client.designation}}</td>
    <td>{{client.company.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

#### AngularJS custom filter

```
App.filter('inArrayExact', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
        if((angular.isArray(arrayFilter.myArray) && arrayFilter.myArray.lenght > 0) &&  || angular.isObject(arrayFilter.myArray)){
            var itemsFound = {};
            angular.forEach(list, function (listItem, key) {
              angular.forEach(arrayFilter.myArray, function (filterItem) {
                 if (angular.isDefined(filterItem[arrayFilter.searchKey]) 
                 && angular.isDefined(listItem[arrayFilter.filterKey])
                 && angular.isDefined(listItem[arrayFilter.filterKey][arrayFilter.searchKey])) {
                   if (angular.isUndefined(itemsFound[key]) 
                   && listItem[arrayFilter.filterKey][arrayFilter.searchKey] == filterItem[arrayFilter.searchKey]) {
                      itemsFound[key] = listItem;
                   }
                 }
              });
            });
            return itemsFound;
        } else {
          return list;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works well. But when the dropdown-items are unselected, the tablelist is empty. Reason: model2 than is an empty array. I now, how to check if an array is not  empty: 

    function nonempty(arr) {
    return !!arr && arr.length > 0;
    }

But how can i  return the whole list in the angular filter when the array is empty  ?

Comment: Okay there is syntax error in the if statement: &&  ||  should be only &&.  Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrtzdev/om6zzn0k/2/ . Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

model2 is an array objects not a string, you need to create a custom filter where you pass model2 and loop over the objects and check the name.

you can check this link on how to build custom filters

https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/